# Angularjs File upload + change the filename

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, file-upload, loopbackjs

I am using the angularjs file upload and using the following package.

http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/

Backend I am using loopback framework, The file upload & file save is working fine , but I unable to rename the file.

For example I upload abcd.img means I try to save based on time or some other. Like abc328767382.jpg, because same file name but different image possible to upload .

Have any options for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful ?

```
uploader.addToQueue(fileHandle, {alias: "someName"});
```

Given that [FileItem](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#fileitem) has the property `alias`